# Android material design - Creating Tool Bar

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) to create material design tool bar. I am at step 7 where my activity should have a color tool bar but my app looks like [image: my app]

for reference, here are my style.xml, color.xml, tool_bar.xml files

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

There was another style.xml in the same folder which has **(21)** next to it. I didn't make any changes to it though.

**color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ColorPrimary">#FF5722</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#E64A19</color>
</resources>
```

**tool_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
If i make changes in stylev21.xml file, I can see my app looks like whats in the tutorial. But if leave style-v21.xml unchanged and make changes in style.xml I don't see those changes. What style*.xml file shall i edit ?

Comment: Follow the 8th step of you tutorial. You will understand. @Em Ae

Comment: But before step 8, the ui should look like step 7. don't you think so ? Thats what the tutorial is implying.

Comment: But you have used `ToolBar` from 9th step before 7th step. Tutorials can have sequence issues. One can understand only after reading it perfectly. You need to follow the proper sequence. @Em Ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of having different styles.xml is that you can add changes specific to the Android version. But then you need to maintain same changes in both the files.

If you are testing your application on device having Android version 5.0 lollipop then style defined in v21/styles.xml will reflect in your application. Otherwise common styles.xml

If you want the same output as displayed in tutorial then I would suggest few changes.

1. Edit your activity_main.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout   

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
         android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
         layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
   ```

P.S. I have just removed margin from `RelativeLayout`.

2. Edit both `styles.xml` and define style which contain no Action bar. E.g. `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

After doing these changes your app will work perfectly on all devices.
I hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, this answer show me a better way to implement. Upvoting from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has the three dots for the context menu , its still showing the action bar . You must have the following line for tool bar to take effect

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

    }
```

Comment: I made changes to styles.xml (v21) and I was able to see the changes. That being said, can you tell me what is `setSupportActionBar` method is ? I mean i can't find it while i am in MainActivity.onCreate method.

Comment: are you using the appcompat library ? its the method to set the tool bar layout as your action bar , you must extent AppCompatActivity instead of the ActionBar activity as mentioned in the tutorial

Comment: Changed the mainactivity and extended it from AppCompatActivity. called `setsupportactionbar`before `setcontentview` and still didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Change your theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` instead of `NoActionBar`.

Then you don't need to add add it in your layout XML file

Also change `android:colorPrimary` to `colorPrimary` (take off `android:`) and `android:colorPrimaryDark` to `colorPrimaryDark`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your **style.xml** like this-

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

*Reason* - AppCompat search for text without "android:"

Comment: I have two style.xmls. 1 is simple and the other one is with v21 (grayed out) which one to change ?

Comment: Simple one, Not the v21